# get the time picked from TimePicker called from Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-timepicker

I have an activity which implements `OnTimeSetListener` and in which I declared a `TimePickerFragment` :

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                (MainActivity) getActivity(), hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pickerHour = hourOfDay;
    pickerMin = minute;
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_hour)).setText(this.pickerHour
            + ":" + this.pickerMin);
}
```

And I call this `TimePicker` from a custom `ArrayAdapter` :

```
TextView hour = (TextView) includeBottom.findViewById(R.id.textView_hour);
        hour.setText(Content.FORMAT_HEURES_RAPPEL.format(rappel.getHeure()));
        hour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RappelAdapter.this.runAnimation2(v);
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(((MainActivity)contexte).getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

            }
        });
```

How can I need to save the hour in database, so I need to know the time picked from the user from the adapter. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the database"? What database are you using?

Comment: you want to know how to get the time picked or how to add to databasE?

Comment: I know how to use the database i am using sqlite. I need to know how to get the time picked from the time picker for each item of my listview as i have a button to select the time for each item of the list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to save hour and min and get it any time in `int` or `string`
save hour and min from `String` or `int` into `SharedPreferences`